# C# - Opening mdi child form from another mdi child form's button

Tags: c#, forms, mdi

Can I actually open another mdi child form using the first mdi child form's button?

```
// Form1 is MdiParent
// Form2 is MdiChild1
// Form3 is MdiChild2

// Form2's code

private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 parentForm = new Form1();
    Form3 childForm2 = new Form3();
    childForm2.MdiParent = parentForm;
    childForm2.Show();
}
```

My problem is when I clicked the button, it didn't showed up

Answer (score 0):

It's appens because you are not showing the `Form1`. If you want show mdi child form do this:

```
Form1 parentForm = new Form1();
Form3 childForm2 = new Form3();
childForm2.MdiParent = parentForm;
parentForm.Show();
childForm2.Show();
```

If `Form1` is your current form and you want display the mdi child form into this form do this:

```
Form3 childForm2 = new Form3();
childForm2.MdiParent = this;
childForm2.Show();
```

P.S. I suggest you to don't use the default name because if you will have much usercontrol it will be mad to discover the correct control